# Tensorflow Keras Sequential vs Functional Inconsistent

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm quite baffled by the inconsistent results I'm getting when using tensorflow keras with the Sequential API.

I have this very straightforward model:

```
def product_cnn_model():
    cnn = keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=False)
    for layer in cnn.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    model = keras.Sequential([
        cnn,
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    ])

    return model
```

But upon calling this function it gives the following error:

```
ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Now this itself is kind of bizarre since my other model:

```
def other_cnn_model():
    cnn = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
        keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    ])
    model = keras.Sequential([
        cnn,
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(106, 106, 64)),
        keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(128)
    ])
    return model
```

works perfectly fine. But what is confusing me more is when I try getting the output using the functional style:

```
x = cnn(x)
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(128)(x)
print(x)
```

It works fine without any errors raised on the `Dense` layers. I must be missing something obvious but I just can't spot it. My brain keeps comparing the model that's failing and the other model and they look almost the same, yet one of them works just fine.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit:** If you want to replicate, the input is of dimensions `(224, 224, 3)`.

You can just use `x = np.random.randn(1, 224, 224, 3)` for example.

Comment: When using `keras.applications.VGG16` with `include_top=False` option, you have to specify `input_shape` parameter. Please read the [docs](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't do that! It works now, thanks. To be honest, they could just raise an error if `input_shape` is not given when `include_top=False`. Also, do you know why it worked with the functional style then? Again, thanks anyways.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked :) Perhaps it works because you pass an output of the `Input` layer to the model when using the functional api, so that the model knows the shape of the input tensor?

Comment: Must be it. Thanks again. If you want you can post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16), the parameter `input_shape` has to be specified when instantiating `VGG16` class with the `include_top=False` option:

> input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top is False

Here is how you can fix the problem. First, define the sequential model:

```
model = Sequential()
```

Second, add the VGG-16 model with the specified `input_shape` parameter:

```
model.add(VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
```

Also, you can use the `InputLayer` before the VGG-16 model. In this case, you don't have to pass the input shape:

```
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(VGG16(include_top=False))
```

Then, define the rest of the model:

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```